How to compress query results?
A large part of the network data and time of our app startup is used by SPARQL query responses sent over the network in uncompressed JSON.
Firefox (dev edition 129.0b9) sends the appropriate request headers but Virtuoso does not seem to accept them. The requests are sent using standard JavaScript fetch requests with URIs of the shape https://ourdomain.de/sparql?query=[...]&format=json.
Is there a way to enable query result compression either on the client side or in our virtuoso server (Docker image from Docker Hub "openlink/virtuoso-opensource-7")?
I am not an expert in HTTP requests and responses but to me it seems as if compression is requested:
Request Headers
GET /sparql?query=[...]format=json HTTP/1.1
Host: www.snik.eu
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:129.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/129.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Referer: https://www.snik.eu/graph/
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Priority: u=4
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2024 07:43:11 GMT
Server: Virtuoso/07.20.3239 (Linux) x86_64-ubuntu_bionic-linux-gnu
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-disposition: filename=sparql_2024-08-01_07-43-11Z.json
Content-Type: application/sparql-results+json
Content-Length: 2766401
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive



did you try to set EnabledGzipContent to 1 in the virtuoso.ini file?

@UninformedUser: I don't have a virtuoso.ini because I am using Docker Compose with environment variables but I have now set the equivalent VIRT_HTTPSERVER_ENABLEDGZIPCONTENT=1 without change in output.

Check your active INI file (default is virtuoso.ini).
You should find EnabledGzipContent in the [HTTPServer] stanza. As documented --

EnabledGzipContent = 0.  This sets the default behavior of HTTP transmission. If set to 1 The Virtuoso HTTP server will send GZipped content to user agents. Otherwise content will be sent as is. The function http_enable_gz() lets you change the server mode on the fly.


Squaring the circle: There was a bug in the code, which has been resolved, as discussed at issue #1308. The answer above remains accurate, and now it works. :-)

That's exactly what I was looking for but failed to find it with the search function using the keyword "compression". I wonder why it is not activated by default, as in my opinion it only has advantages if requested by the appropriate headers.

Neither setting VIRT_HTTPSERVER_ENABLEDGZIPCONTENT=1 in docker-compose.yml nor http_enable_gz(); in setup.sql enable compression for me. In contrast, when I go to https://dbpedia.org/sparql, I see the ContentEncoding header set to gzip but this is not set when using my own instance.

Does this work in every Virtuoso version? I notice that it is active for DBpedia, which uses Virtuoso version 8, while I am using open source version 7.

P.S.: Even when I go directly into the Virtuoso container and run http_enable_gz(1) in ISQL, it does not change the behavior.

This should work in every recent, if not every every, Virtuoso version. Would you mind reporting the problem you're having to the Virtuoso Open Source project?

Sure! I reported it at https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/1308.

@KonradHöffner — Fixed by commit a09ba10. Thank you for reporting!

Thank you for the quick fix! For other readers: As of 2024-08-13, you need to use the latest Virtuoso beta image pkleef/virtuoso-opensource-7 because this fix is not yet in the latest release of openlink/virtuoso-opensource-7. You can verify it works with docker run --rm --network=host -e VIRT_HTTPSERVER_ENABLEDGZIPCONTENT=1 pkleef/virtuoso-opensource-7 and then open http://localhost:8890/sparql with the browser dev tools network tab open and then you see it in the response headers and also the transferred size is smaller.
